# Get the row count and all row data from a mysql/mysqli SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, mysql-num-rows

I am using a SELECT query to get the data from a number of rows and I also want to get the count of the rows.

When I use `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {` it will list all entries.

The problem that I am encountering is that while all the entries are successfully counted and the right number is listed, only the latest entry is selected and listed when I echo `$row['title']`.

If I delete `, COUNT(*) as total` then it selects all correctly, but I was wondering if it was possible to use `COUNT()` and `SELECT *`.

My problematic query:

```
SELECT *,
       COUNT(*) as total
FROM new_messages
WHERE username='$session->username'
```

Comment: Related content: [Is it possible to combine num_rows with fetch_all() into a single execute_query in PHP 8.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77728616/2943403) and  [how to get count of mysql_fetch_array using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38837430/2943403) and [Count length of Array php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22677992/2943403) and [mysqli counting results and fetching them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28838218/2943403)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you shouldn't be using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` because the `mysql_` functions are obsolete.

At the least, you should switch to using the [MySQL Improved Extension (mysqli) functions](http://php.net/mysqli) or alternatively the more general [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) functions.

If you use mysqli, you can use [`mysqli_result->num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to count the number of rows in your result, there's a code example on that page showing how to use it.

PDO has no function for counting rows in a result set, but you can use [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and then just check the size of the array you fetched into.

And just for completeness, if you stick with the `mysql_` functions (which you shouldn't, because you're risking security problems), you could use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Comment: that was a really interesting response. I always appreciate responses that go above and beyond and teach me more then I bargained for. \ I have never heard of the pdo or mysqli extensions. Why are they better and which one is better pdo, or mysqli? You mentioned security, but can I not just use mysql_real_escape_string? Do they increase performance, or are just easier to use?

Comment: I don't know that one or the other is particularly "better", PDO is built to work with multiple databases though, while mysqli applies only to mysql. This can mean that learning PDO could be more useful, because you would be able to use the same PDO functions if you ever work on a different database backend, such as postgresql or sqlite. The main advantage of using these instead of the basic mysql functions is that they support Parameterized Statements which make SQL injection impossible: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection#Parameterized_statements

Comment: If you stick to using `mysql_real_escape_string` you *should* be safe, but if someone ever finds a vulnerability in that function, all your code will suddenly be exploitable. This is the reason that `mysql_real_escape_string` even exists in the first place, because a hole was discovered in `mysql_escape_string`. This is a non-issue with parameterized statements.

Comment: does PDO work with ORACLE. I was just curious, because if mysql ever becomes obsolete in a sense that my data build up becomes too large, I would obviously have to switch databases. Thanks a lot for your responses, really appreciate it.

Comment: also you said paramaterized, couldn't someone just use a malicious parameter. Because those parameters would still be userinput right? Or is the input checked in the parameter equation?

Comment: Yes, it supports Oracle, the list of drivers currently available is here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php  As for parameters, no, the purpose of parameters is to make it impossible for the value to "break out" into the query. They take care of any necessary escaping/etc for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to fetch all records anyway count the records on the client-side (as seen from the MySQL's perspective, i.e. your php script).
If you're using an unbuffered query fetch all records first then call the function/methods that counts the result records (e.g. mysql_num_rows() ). If you're using a buffered query the order of function/method calls doesn't matter.

p.s.: You only get the value of "the last record" because using an aggregate function like Count() without a GROUP BY clause makes *all* records one group. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html
MySQL allows you to select columns that are not part of the GROUP BY clause, but http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html says:

> When using this feature, all rows in each group should have the same values for the columns that are ommitted from the GROUP BY part. *The server is free to return any value from the group*, so the results are indeterminate unless all values are the same.

Comment: That was a really great, informative response, if I could vote up multiple times I would. Just one question, you mentioned buffered and unbuffered query, what is the difference?

Comment: A buffered query transfers all result records from the MySQL server to the php process before the function/method returns (e.g. mysql\_query()) while the data for an unbuffered query (e.g. mysql\_unbuffered\_query) is only transferred when you actually fetch a record, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-use-result.html

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need count for each row? You only need to fetch it once, you can use `mysql_num_rows` for that:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_messages WHERE username='$session->username");
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);
```

Or you can fetch the count directly:

```
list($count) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM new_messages WHERE username='$session->username"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query doesn't make much sense because there is no GROUP BY to support the `COUNT()` call.  [PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/U4)

```
SELECT *,
       COUNT(*) as total
FROM new_messages
WHERE username=?
```

Executing such a prepared statement (while `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`) will result in an error.

> Fatal error: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, [...]

Even if your the query did work, would you expect each fetched row to contain the same redundant count? That would be too much redundant data.

---

Because `mysql_` functions are obsolete, I'll omit them from my demonstrations. No matter if you use mysqli's `query()`, `execute()` a mysqli prepared statement, or enjoy mysqli's `execute_query()` from PHP8.2, all result objects can be used in exactly the same way.

Access the prepopulated `num_rows` property of the result object to get the number of fetched rows.

Using the same result object, you can unconditionally iterate all rows with a simple `foreach()` as if it the result object was an indexed array of associative arrays.  There is no need to call a `fetch()` method over and over inside of a loop.

If you are not mutating the result data and merely passing the data to another layer (or to another environment), then it will be completely sensible to call `fetch_all()` instead of generating the 2d array via manually looping.

---

Truthfully, I am struggling to imagine a scenario where it is useful to access all rows from a SELECT query AND count the rows.  I mean, if you are going to convert the result object's row data into a multidimensional array, then just call PHP's `count()` function on that generated array when/where it is needed.

If you are trying to determine if ANY rows were fetched, just make a truthy check on the generated 2d array. An empty array will loosely evaluate as `false`, otherwise `true`.

---

Finally, if you must count the rows in the result set and access the data in the result set, here is a non-exhaustive collection of demonstrations which get the count using `num_rows`.

All prepared statements below will use `SELECT * FROM new_messages WHERE username=?` as `$sql`. Non-prepared statements will hardcode the search string. All examples below produce the exact same result:

`execute_query()`: [PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/1p):

```
$obj = $mysqli->execute_query($sql, [$session->username]);
var_export([
    'total' => $obj->num_rows,
    'data' => $obj->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
]);
```

[IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35044452/2943403) (to avoid declaring `$obj` globally) with `execute_query()`: [PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/vp)

```
var_export(
    (fn($obj) => [
        'total' => $obj->num_rows,
        'data' => $obj->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
    ])($mysqli->execute_query($sql, [$session->username]))
);
```

`execute()` [PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/lp):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$session->username]);
$obj = $stmt->get_result();
var_export([
    'total' => $obj->num_rows,
    'data' => $obj->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
]);
```

`execute()` with `foreach()`: [PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/up)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$session->username]);
$obj = $stmt->get_result();
$result = [
    'total' => $obj->num_rows,
    'data' => [],
];
foreach ($obj as $row) {
    $result['data'][] = $row;
}
var_export($result);
```

`query()` with no parameters: [PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/r4)

```
$obj = $mysqli->query($sql);
var_export([
    'total' => $obj->num_rows,
    'data' => $obj->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
]);
```

`query()` with `foreach()`: [PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/q4)

```
$obj = $mysqli->query($sql);
$result = [
    'total' => $obj->num_rows,
    'data' => [],
];
foreach ($obj as $row) {
    $result['data'][] = $row;
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: "The following query doesn't make much sense" sentence **instantly** makes a bad answer. As it addresses the OP instead of wider audience. When making a generic answer, I always edit the question, to weed out all that silly stuff. Nobody cares about petty blunders that OP had a century ago.

Comment: You don't think it is considerate to clarify XY Problems to readers? I don't mind if you wish to edit the question.  I think it is unfair to deem this very generous/comprehensive answer to be "bad".