# mysqli counting results and fetching them

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

Hello I have a prepared statement and I need to count the number of results I get. In order to do this I use store_result and num_rows

```
$query = 'SELECT userId, promo, email FROM users WHERE active = ?';
$rsActivation = $db->prepare($query);
$rsActivation->bind_param('s', $actv);
$rsActivation->execute();
$rsActivation->store_result();

$totalRows = $rsActivation->num_rows;
```

This code manages to get me the number of rows. The problem is that if I do this I cannot use fetch() on $rsActivation. If I use fetch and not use store_result I cannot get the number of rows.

How can I accomplish both things?

Thanks

**SOLVED:**

Turns out my problem was I was trying to fetch the results as an associative array. Instead I used bind_result to assign values to variables. Then I was able to use store_result and num_rows to get the count and after that I used fetch() together with the variables I assigned in bind_result.

```
$query = 'SELECT userId, promo, email FROM users WHERE active = ?';
$rsActivation = $db->prepare($query);
$rsActivation->bind_param('s', $actv);
$rsActivation->execute();

$rsActivation->bind_result($userId, $promo, $email);

$rsActivation->store_result();
$totalRows = $rsActivation->num_rows;

while($rsActivation->fetch()){
    echo "<p>". $userId ."</p>";
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you asking essentially, "where does store_result() store the result?"? I think that would have been a better title for the question...

Answer (score -1):

You can try using

```
...
$rsActivation->execute();
$results = $rsActivation->get_results();

$totalRows = $results->num_rows;
```

and you should be able to fetch using something like

$results->fetch_assoc(), $results->fetch_row(), etc.

Here's the doc for it: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is get_result requires mysqlnd. I have no idea how to install that either in MAMP or in the GoDaddy server. :(