# Given execute_query() allows convenient one-liners, can I have the data and the count (num_rows) in a single call?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using the new mysqli::execute_query in PHP 8.2 and want to get the total number of orders placed by a customer and an array of the orders.

Simplified code:

```
$MySQLi = new mysqli( "host", "username", "password", "database");

$sql = "select * from orders WHERE userid = ? ";

$ordercount = $MySQLi->execute_query($sql, [$userid])->num_rows;
$orderdata = $MySQLi->execute_query($sql, [$userid])->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Can it be done with just a single execute_query ?

Comment: The fact that `execute_query()` is called is completely irrelevant.  The advice remains the same.  Use the advice given a decade ago: "_fetch all records first then call the function/methods that counts the result records_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution to this: don't do it in one line. Just because `mysqli_execute_query()` lets you do things in one line doesn't mean it's a good idea.

You can save the result in a variable, then access the `num_rows` property and fetch the rows, all on separate lines.

```
$result = $MySQLi->execute_query($sql, [$userid]);
$ordercount = $result->num_rows;
$orderdata = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

However, the `num_rows` property is quite useless (the same goes for its function equivalent). It is exactly the same as getting the count of elements in the fetched array.

```
$orderdata = $MySQLi->execute_query($sql, [$userid])->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$ordercount = count($orderdata);
```

So, if you want to do it in one line and get the count of rows, you can just use [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

Answer (score 3):

When we have the data, we can always have the count without num_rows:

```
$sql = "select * from orders WHERE userid= ? ORDER BY orderid DESC";
$orderdata = $MySQLi->execute_query($sql, [$userid])->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$ordercount = count($orderdata);
```

In case only one record is selected, the fetched row can be used as a count value (or, rather, as a flag that tells whether a record was found or not), i.e.

```
$sql = "select * from users WHERE id=?";
$user = $MySQLi->execute_query($sql, [$userid])->fetch_assoc();
if ($user) { ...
```

Comment: Topic well covered and demonstrated at earlier page: [Get the row count and all row data from a mysql/mysqli SELECT query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77740512/2943403)